# Facebook Landing Page - webpage within a landing page

Tags: facebook

I've seen landing pages within Facebook that are a working version of a different website with in the landing page, but now that I'm trying to show somebody else an example of this, I can't find one. Does anyone know of an example of this and can you share the link with me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/